# Adroid apk has assigned values to %d. Changing it to 20%d only outputs 20 before the assigned value. how can I add 20 to %d so output is sum of the 2

Tags: android, apk, android-resources, arscnview

For example
Coins %d

Jus to change the number to be displayed in app such %d + 20 = 30 when %d is 10. And not 20%d which just gives out 2010 when %d is 10

Comment: Have you tried like this: `String.format("Coins: %d", coins + 20)`?

Comment: The value is  in resources.arsc and i haven't found a way to extract the files and then archive them back to arsc format..... So iam using arsc editor of which doesn't open the resource source code....